# Ruby development right on host

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is it possible to work on files directly on a host from my desktop?  I keep hearing that windows sucks for Ruby dev, and my hosting company offers RoR (bluehost.com), so I'm wondering if I even really need anything on my local machine besides a text editor hitting the remote files and maybe an FTP.

Comment: You can but it really doesn't mean that you should!

Comment: LOL, one of the things RoR does really well is enable you to work in more or less identical environments in development and production, and have them behave the same way. Don't fight it!

Comment: (but yes, you technically could just edit files on the remote host, and assuming you have SSH and access to restart the application running under mod_passenger or something, you can control it remotely) Likewise, if the host allows you to connect remotely to the database, you could even fire up a rails console from your local machine into the remote database.

Comment: Good points :)  I have a Linux box I just set up, and I'm wanting to learn Ruby, not Linux :)  I think i have to bite the bullet once and for all and just go linux.  Why is Windows such a nightmare from what I've read.

Comment: Another thing to look out for, is a new (in beta atm) coding environment: [Koding.com](http://koding.com), which supports in browser Ruby/Rails development and free basic hosting. I wouldn't say it's a great place to do intense development at the moment, but it sure could be.

Comment: Note that Ruby development on Windows really is not very bad. I love Ruby, and I dislike Windows, but I have done a lot of Ruby development on Windows, OS X, and Ubuntu and can say from experience: the Windows experience is mostly fine.

Comment: The only things I can think of that make Ruby development on Windows slightly more work: 1) cmd.exe doesn't use utf-8 encoding; 2) Reading files will translate `\r\n` into `\n` unless you remember to open in 'binary' mode; 3) using [Thin](http://code.macournoyer.com/thin/) for serving (which I prefer) is annoying to kill: often ctrl-c doesn't cut it until you make another request to the server (refresh the browser) and then you need to ctrl-c again. Both items #1 and #2 are largely irrelevant for Rails development.

Comment: Koding.com might be exactly what I'm looking for to get started.  Thanks!  I'm going to go home this weekend and play around with things.

Answer (score 4):

Does your provider offer ssh access to your server? If it does, you can just clone your repository somewhere under your home directory and work on it through ssh using vim, or some other editor. That would be very similar to working locally, but you would have the power of the *nix environment at your disposal.

In this case, you could keep several terminals open and you can run your tests, edit the code, commit with git, and so on. If you don't have ssh access, then I think this doesn't make sense - you would use the possibility to run your tests quickly, etc.

If you want to work remotely you will need:

1. Some kind off ssh client for windows - I like [mRemoteNG](http://www.mremoteng.org)
2. Rails stack installed on the server (check with [Rails download page](http://rubyonrails.org/download) for current versions and how to install them)
3. Probably git installed (if it's not there, see [Pro Git](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Getting-Started-Installing-Git) on how to install)
4. Familiarity with vim or some other editor running in terminal

You can do all that on your local linux machine as well - you just don't need to use ssh then. You can also install Linux in a virtual machine and run it alongside windows.

Comment: I believe it does.  I guess my question should have been more how to get started.  I've done the tryruby in the browser stuff.  Just not sure what step to take next.  I have Linux set up on my machine at home, should I continue trying to familiarize myself?

Comment: I updated my answer with some more details. It definitely feels nicer to work with Ruby and Rails on a *nix machine, mostly because Ruby is much faster and there're less problems with native gems.

Comment: So would your suggestion be to just bite the bullet and try to get my linux environment up and running, build some small stuff, and then worry about deploying, hosting etc?  I just saw that my host had the capability so I thought it might be worth investigating it rather than spinning my wheels learning linux and getting it set up properly.  Now that I wrote that, it sounds like that's part of the learning process anyway :)

Comment: Unless you're developing in .NET, any production deployment will be on some kind of *nix stack. So it's useful to learn it anyway. With distributions like Ubuntu and deployment to Heroku there's not much you need to know to start.

Comment: I started playing around with Heroku last night and will continue playing with that.  I think learning the basics without having to set things up is both good and bad, but at this point, I just want to concentrate on writing code.

Answer (score 3):

That sounds extremely ugly to work with. If you are on Windows, consider [RailsInstaller](http://railsinstaller.org/), which should help with getting a good development environment to run.

For hosting, I can highly recommend [Heroku](http://www.heroku.com). Their [Getting started with Rails 3.x on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3) guide will help you deploy your first app in a quarter of an hour.

As a Text Editor, it's good to pick any and learn it by heart. A great one available for most platforms is [SublimeText 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/).

Comment: Looks like it could get kind of pricey, tho, right?  I have Linux installed, I'm wondering if i should dig down and really commit to using it, or just chuck it and go back to Windows.

Comment: If your Heroku app gets pricey, it means you have a ton of actual users on your site. Rails has a lot of optimization and caching included by default that's very easy to integrate, so you'll be able to scale quite nicely on Heroku. It's definitely worth it!

Comment: Considering Linux and Windows: Ruby development from what I've heard is best done on Unix systems, which leaves Linux and Mac. From what I can see the majority of people in Ruby / Rails develop on Mac OS X. My recommendation would be to try using Ruby on any environment, but when you decide to develop at a commercial scale consider switching to Mac. Reason: There is lots of development environment stuff that is crafted for Mac, like the pow development server etc. I added an editor for any environment recommendation above.

Comment: Unrelated sidenote: Chrome warns me that your website contains Malware!

Comment: Thomas, thanks, I know.  I got nailed with a php hack a while back and cleared all of it out.  I was looking into wiping it out and putting a simple ruby blog in it's place :)  That's what started all of this stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely - with a remote linux server, it's very easy to develop in Rails. Any friction involved would be far less than the hassles of trying to develop on Windows. There are a few things to do:

- Make sure your security is set up so that only **certain IP addresses** can access the development ports.
- Either use a **terminal-based editor** such as `vim` (great option for remote or local), or use a GUI editor that helps you edit remote files. Textmate on OSX can do this via an SSH connection, for example. You just don't want to be constantly running `rsync` manually every time you save.
- Make sure that you can **STOP** your remote instance without **TERMINATING** it. This is possible with an EBS-backed instance with Amazon EC2, for example. Having an instance that you can pause/start at-will allows you to develop on a speedier box while saving a lot money.